# Node.JS, как закрыть открытые порты

Tags: windows, node.js

Как закрыть порты, которые остались открытые после выполнения запуска сервера через обычный http?

Какая это команда **в консоли**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы не можете закрывать сокеты без завершения процесса, которому принадлежат эти сокеты. Сокеты принадлежат процессу, который их открыл. Для поиска ID процесса используйте

```
netstat -aon | findstr :%номер_порта%
```

Также можно использовать tcpview (gui) и Tcpvcon (command line).
Для завершения процесса используйте

```
taskkill /f /pid %PID%
```

Или можно через диспетчер задач закрыть.

Comment: Чего я и ожидал, чёрт побери. Благодарю.